# How to make Emacs not highlight trailing whitespace in term?

Tags: emacs

I'm using this in my .emacs config

```
 '(show-trailing-whitespace t)
```

And I'm generally very happy with it.
The only problem is that it highlights whitespace when I'm in 'M-x term' buffer and I have no control over that whitespace. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
(add-hook
 'term-mode-hook
 (lambda() (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```