# how to set c-toggle-flag and c-syntactic-indentation to nil only in ecmascript-mode in emacs?

Tags: javascript, emacs

I am using multi-web-mode in emacs in order to edit html pages with javascript and php. When I use ecmascript-mode for javascript I get some troubles with the indentation because of the variables c-toggle-flag and c-syntactic-indentation. I have tried to set them to nil:

```
(setq-default c-electric-flag nil)
(setq-default c-syntactic-indentation nil)
```

But this sets the variables to nil even when I am editing php in another mode.

I want to set them to **nil** only in ecmascript-mode and keep them **t** while editing php in another mode. How can I do that?

Comment: I've just answered a similar question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126575/how-to-make-emacs-not-highlight-trailing-whitespace-in-term. Just use `ecmascript-mode-hook` in appropriate place.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to fix it from this morning! :)